# How to make a layout with Styled Components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Since the point of React is to make components reusable, and the layout of a page can change drastically from one app to another, I'm not sure where to put my layout-specific styles. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The placement of a component should be decided by the 'consumer' of the component. So, for example, if you have 3 components:

- `ComponentA`

  - `ComponentB`

    - `ComponentC`

---

- `ComponentC` would decide the placement all its sub-components.
- `ComponentB` would decide the placement all its sub-components, which
  would include `ComponentC`
- `ComponentA` would decide the placement all its sub-components, which
  would include `ComponentB`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean global styles in React you have two options:

option 1 : throw them in as a regular CSS file - see how `Create-React-App` does it - or just add them to you `index/html` where you're rendering the app.

option 2: Styled Components has support for Theming, meaning they give you a `<ThemeProvider />` element and then you can use the provided styles in any component downstream. Here are [the docs including a basic example](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming).

If on the other hand you're referring layouts but on a component / sub component level, you basically pull the layout styles as far up as you can. An example would be having a  element with its own styles; something like this:

```
// Layout.js
const myStyledContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
`
export default (props) => <myStyledContainer>{props.children}</myStyledContainer>
```

Then in you `App.js` you'd have something like:

```
return (
<Layout>

*... your other components or pages or whatever*
</Layout>
```

It's a matter of opinion so just try things and see what works for your project.